# Spring Integration Wrong Host Header

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We've been experiencing this weird problem with the request Host header being set as the application's URL. This results to the external system to not handle our requests.

Here's the DEBUG log of apache of the `Spring Integration application` hosted on `localhost:8082`. Don't mind the content for now but the Content-Type will be a problem subsequently:

```
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /health HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "cookie: PHPSESSID=ost897ibh0j7rovf2rudr33c22[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "host: localhost:8082[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/xml[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "user-agent: PostmanRuntime/6.1.6[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 4[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "test"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "27[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"success":true,"message":"Service up"}"
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
```

and here's the request done with curl:

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:9292/health
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9292 (#0)
> POST /health HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9292
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

So with Spring Integration 
`org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "host: localhost:8082[\r][\n]"`

and with curl 
`> Host: localhost:9292`

We can easily solve the `host` problem in Spring Integration by setting the header mapper of the outgate: 
`handler.setHeaderMapper(new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper());`

```
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /health HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json, application/*+json[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 4[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:9292[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_112)[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "test"
```

So we were able to solve the problem with the `Host` header, unfortunately, it seems that the `Content-Type` set through an enricher has been ignored and has been set to `text/plain` instead of `application/xml`.

What seems to be the problem here? I'm assuming this has to do with just using a basic DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.

Here's the flow configuration snippet:

```
public class BasicIntegrationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel basicRequestChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel basicResponseChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessagingGatewaySupport basicInGate() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway handler = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();

        RequestMapping mapping = new RequestMapping();
        mapping.setPathPatterns("api/v1/basic");
        mapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.GET);
        mapping.setProduces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
        handler.setRequestMapping(mapping);

        handler.setRequestChannel(basicRequestChannel());
        handler.setReplyChannel(basicResponseChannel());

        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler basicOutGate() {
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler =
                new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost:9292/health");
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(BaseResponse.class);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        handler.setHeaderMapper(new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper());
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow basicFlow() {
        return (IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> f) -> f
                .channel(basicRequestChannel())
                .log("basic")
                .handle((GenericHandler<Object>) (o, map) -> "test")
                .enrichHeaders(e -> e.header(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, true))
                .log("basic")
                .handle(basicOutGate())
                .log("basic")
                .enrichHeaders(e -> e.header(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, true))
                .channel(basicResponseChannel());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
DefaultHttpHeaderMapper mapper = DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper();
mapper.setExcludedOutboundStandardRequestHeaderNames(new String[] { "Host" });
handler.setHeaderMapper(mapper);
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise and correct answer @Gary Russel! I was looking into http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/http/support/DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.html while in traffic, should have done that before posting the question.