# Spring Integration with multiple http outbound gateway does not clear the header

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In a situation where I have:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="dataHubRawDataUploadChannel"
        id="raw" url-expression="headers['rawUrl']" http-method="POST"
        extract-request-payload="true" header-mapper="headerMapper"
        reply-channel="rawDataUploadResponseChannel" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" 
         error-handler="rawResponseErrorHandler" />

    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="canonicalHttpChannel"
        id="canonical" url-expression="headers['canonicalUrl']"
        http-method="POST" header-mapper="headerMapper" reply-channel="targetDataUploadChannel"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"    rest-template="customRestTemplate"/>


    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="targetHttpChannel"
        id="target" url-expression="headers['targetUrl']"
        http-method="POST" header-mapper="headerMapper" reply-channel="targetUploadResponseProcessor"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" />
```

I face the following problem:

**The headers of the first and second request are not cleared when sending the third request** , resulting in a Http 400 response.

I tried to clean the headers but the only solution I found is to override the RestTemplate class responsible for the actual HTTP request and clear the headers there, which is an ugly solution.

Do you have a better way to do it with Spring Integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` has a method `setExcludedOutboundStandardRequestHeaderNames` where you can pass it an array of header names that you don't want propagated from the outbound message.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908154/spring-integration-wrong-host-header/44909468#44909468) for an example.

**EDIT**

If you are using Java configuration, simply define that mapper as a `@Bean` as shown in that answer.

If you are using XML configuration:

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
        factory-method="outboundMapper">
    <property name="excludedInboundStandardResponseHeaderNames">
        <array>
            <value>Host</value>
            <value>User-Agent</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: My problem now is that when I configure this at xml level such as:  


`<!-- Configuration for header mapper for outboud gateways -->
 <bean id="headerMapper" scope="prototype"
  class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
  <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
  <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
  <property name="excludedOutboundStandardRequestHeaderNames" value="[fileName]"/>
 </bean>
`
It would not exclude that field called fileName

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's unreadable; edit the question instead. Since you are using `*` in the outbound header names you're overriding the exclusions. You should use the factory method to create the outbound adapter as in that sample (use `factory-method` in XML).

Comment: Sorry my first post on Stack Overflow! Thanks for the advices, do you happen to have a code sample for a similar case ? i am new with spring integrations ..